# URL links stop working after PHP full page loaded - PHP SESSION ISSET

Tags: php, html, session, session-cookies, session-variables

I have a menu which is in menu.php

In my page.php I have

```
<?php
include 'menu.php';
?>
```

This works great but one link stops working one the page fully loads.

The menu.php file looks like so

```
<li>
    <a href="availability.php">
    <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>Availability - 6 Weeks</a>
</li>


<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] == true){

?>


                    <li>
                                <a href="tv-usage-monthly-current.php">
                                <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>Availability - Current Month</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="js-arrow" href="logout.php">
                            <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>LOGOUT</a>
                    </li>
                    <?php

} else {
?>

                    <li>
                        <a class="js-arrow" href="login.php">
                            <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>LOGIN</a>
                    </li>
<?php

}
?>
```

The `availability.php` url always shows (if logged in or not)

The `tv-usage-monthly-current.php` & `logout.php` shows only for logged in users.

The `login.php` only shows for not logged in users. It works whilst the page is loading but not once the page has stopped loading. It still shows, and can be right clicked and opened, if you hover over the correct URL shows at the bottom, however it just can't be clicked...

Answer (score 0):

If you can't click it, there might be something overlapping the link, such as an element or in your case maybe the `fontawesome` icon. I suggest removing the icon class on the `<i>` (temporarily) and seeing if the links work now, if they do, they you could try setting the `z-index` of your `<a>` to 99 in CSS in order to have it overlap the icon instead.

```
a {
    z-index: 99;
}
```